# How to create a function to save information in dictionary from a csv file in python

Tags: python

I am writing and testing a function for opening a .csv file and save information in a dictionary, instead of using import csv.

The csv file is like:

```
16SAP,12/02/24,sapin-9,MATEYIJDNS
FAS1,01/02/21,fasiculata,MTYEUSOLD
EDS5,10/20/20,epsilon,MHGSJDKDLSKDKDJS
etc....
```

and .csv file has a (,) separated format and 4 fields: identifier, date, name and sequence, respectively.

My code is:

```
def dicfromcsv(csv_file):
    with open('csv_file', 'r') as f:
        d = {}
        l = f.read().split(',')
        for i in l:
            values = i.split(':')
            d[values[0]] = values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]

dicfromcsv('PDB.csv')
```

But it doesn't function.

Thank in advance

Comment: can you use the panda's library instead?
this may help you https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/pandas_csv.asp

Comment: There's no `:` in your file, what is `i.split(':')` supposed to do?

Comment: Perhaps Python's `csv` module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: You're not processing the file line by line. `l` is not a line, it's one of the comma-separator fields in the file.

Comment: `with open('csv_file'` is going to try to open a file literally named "csv_file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't quote `csv_file`, you want to use the value of the variable.
2. Use the `csv` module to parse the file.
3. Loop over the records in the file, rather than splitting the entire file at `,` characters.
4. You can use a list slice to get all the fields of the record after the first field.
5. Your file only has 4 fields, there's no `values[4]`

```
import csv

def dicfromcsv(csv_file):
    d = {}
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        csvf = csv.reader(f)
        for values in csvf:
            d[values[0]] = tuple(values[1:])
    return d
```